# Change Sandbox Email

Tags: email, user

In a sandbox, how do I change the email back to the sandbox example email?

Current: `Jsmith@gmail.com`

I want to change it back to: `Jsmith=gmail.com@example.com`

How do I do this without the ability to verify?

Answer (score 1):

Simple,

In your sandbox go to Email Administration->Deliverability-> Make that as **No email**

Now when you change email of user make sure to check "Generate New Password and Notify user immediately "

[image]

So what is going on is, we are setting new email as well as a new password, But as we have disabled the email deliverability the password reset mail won't be set and as we have triggered email change it will be updated in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class to run and update the information. If you want it every time that your Sandbox is updated, you should create a SandboxPostCopy

Here some documentation -> https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_deployment_sandbox_postcopy_script.htm

Comment: It will allow to change user's email...which is goal of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually...just update user's email as example one and check the box send reset password immediately given at bottom of page. It will change the email address without verification.